# How to know image is existing using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have image attribute with src. I want to know when I delete image from server it should display image not exist in alt attribute. else it should display image. I am testing this with alert but dont know which keyword to use.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
alert($('img').attr('src'))     
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/momenticons-gloss-basic/momenticons-gloss-basic/32/information2.png" />
</body>
```

Comment: You mean when image no more exists on server, set attribute alt to "image not exist", correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If an `img` element src returns a `404` (or any other http result other than `200`) it wil raise an `error` event which you can trap.

Try this:

```
$("img").error(function(){
    $(this).hide(); // hide image
    // or you can display a generic 'not found' image
});
```

Comment: Is error triggered for image already in browser's cache? Just wondering.

Comment: @roasted no, I don't believe it is as it would return a 200 result. I could be wrong though.

Comment: That's... WOW! I didn't even expect that jQuery has something like that :)

Answer (score 5):

jQuery allows you to bind an error event handler on for these cases.

You could do the following:

```
$('img').error(function(){ $(this).hide(); }).attr('alt', 'Does not exist');
```

EDIT: you can read more here: http://api.jquery.com/error/

Comment: was typing the same while you did, guess youre faster :D

Comment: In fact, I would not recommend updating ALT. Simply replace the source to a holding image or hide it all together!